# stopping scanf on pressing enter

Tags: c, string

I am writing a C program which takes string input and print each word in a separate line. But the program is not stopping even after pressing enter. Please suggest a solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[50];
    while(scanf("%s",str)&&strcmp(str,"\n"))
        printf("%s\n",str);

}
```

Comment: `scanf` does not read newline

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fgets to read the line and if the input is just a single character which is newline character then break else keep continuing.

```
while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin))
{
   if(strcmp(str,"\n") == 0)
   break;
   else
   {
     size_t n = strlen(str);
     if(n>0 && str[n-1] == '\n')
     str[n-1] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n",str);
   }
}
```

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline character and we need to supress the newline character as shown above.

Comment: Thanks but if i want to take each word of the string in a new char string??

Comment: @RITIKAGUPTA Then you need break the input into tokens using space as delimiter . The handy function to do it is `strtok()`